# Marking new entries on Microsoft Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working on Microsoft Access Database. I have a query contains a 'requery' command on its OnLoad method, so the query will automatically updates a new entry whenever I add new records in a table corresponds to the query. My question is, my supervisor wants me to mark the new updated entry on the query (which already had modified into a form), so the admins will notice that the table has been updated and there are new record included to the form. More likely, some kind of mark the rows that containing new update with different color. Does Microsoft Access has that kind of functionality?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is conditional formatting which you can use to change colours based on data. You could create a field which changes when the row is updated and the colour changes based on this field.

https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-6ba9e9fa-4347-4183-b335-44e43b05e22f

As far as I am aware though, a query doesn't change records, it only pulls existing records. So if you want to highlight new entries you need to do this based on information stored within that record or create a new field for this purpose.